# How to play mp in other java class than MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have two java classes: MainActivity and Explosion. I want to use this code in the Explosion java class. (this, R.raw.explosionsound) doesn't work and (Explosion.this, R.raw.explosionsound) also doesn't work. 
How do I fix this?

```
    MediaPlayer mp = null;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.explosionsound);
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();

        }
    });
```

Comment: you´re calling `release()` even before trying to start the sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Explosion is not an activity then you must supply a Context to instantiate the MediaPlayer object.

```
Explosion explosion = new Explosion(context);
explosion.play();

class Explosion{
    Context context;

    public Explosion(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void play(){
       MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.explosionsound);
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.stop();
               mp.release();
           }
       });
       mp.start();
    }
}
```

Also as it was allready pointed out you can't release the MediaPlayer object and then call start();